# Unable to cast Combobox.SelectedValue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, casting

My code goes like this for simple practise problem which i am trying to build. I come across

> Invalid Cast Exception. Specified Cast is not valid.

```
public Form1()
{
      Combobox1.Datasource = foo.bar.dataset.tables[0];
      Combobox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
      Combobox1.ValueMember = "ID";
 }

 private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      NewClass P2 = new NewClass;
      P2.Filter.Id = (long)Combobox1.SelectedValue;
 }
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how to go about solving it even though I have typecasted Combobox1.SelectedValue object?

Comment: Did you debug and check which type Combobox1.SelectedValue really is?

Comment: Can you show how foo.bar.dataset.tables[0] is initialized?

Comment: @Vale: I tried searching and found that Combobox.SelectedValue is of object type and so i had to typecast it with long....

Comment: And what does the object contain?

Comment: @EvrenKuzucuoglu Well I am little constrained here... What exactly would you like to know for this?

Comment: @mabus44 Be sure to check that tables[0] is enumerable (i.e. a list or something) and each of its elements has an ID member that can be cast to a long (i.e it's an int, a long, a decimal, etc).

Comment: Concerning Vale's comment and your response: everything in .net is an object. It's also going to be something else, at runtime. To know what, set a breakpoint on the P2.Filter.Id line, and when it stops there, set a watch on Combobox1.SelectedValue The watch window will tell you what actual type this object is

Comment: @EvrenKuzucuoglu : Thanks ... its System.Data.DataRowView ...

Comment: So the answer by Forlan07 is correct: cast the selected value into DataRowView, then use the cast value as you please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
P2.Filter.Id = Convert.ToInt64(Combobox1.SelectedValue);
```

According to your comment this might help:

```
P2.Filter.Id = Convert.ToInt64((Combobox1.SelectedValue as DataRowView).Item[0]);
```

Comment: @mabus44 Obviously your SelectedValue is a "DataRowView". You will have to cast the SelectedValue and then get the item you need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this happens, maybe someone can help me on that but I would prefer going.

```
      P2.Filter.Id = Convert.ToInt64(Combobox1.SelectedValue);
```

That always works for me when I have this issue.

Comment: Didn't Work out.                                                 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: @mabus44 look at my answer, maybe it helps

Comment: @mabus44 how are you databinding?

Answer (score 2):

`ComboBox.SelectedValue` is obviously not a `long`. You should do whatever is required to change its type; most probably this would be

```
P2.Filter.Id = Convert.ToInt64(ComboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Didn't Work out. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Answer (score 2):

Check the object reference before you cast *SelectedValue*.

```
long value=0l;
if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
 {
 value=long.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
 }
```

You can use *SelectedItem* property which will returns the reference of `DataRowView` (row).

```
 DataRowView row = comboBox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView ;
 if (row != null){
     MessageBox.Show("value " + row[0] + " " + row[1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting a string to long is mal-casting. SelectedValue is supposed to return a string that needs Convert.ToLong to operate on

Comment: Convert.ToLong? never heard of that 1 before X-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert.ToInt64(Combobox1.SelectedValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather try something like

[Convert.ToInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint64%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Converts a specified value to a 64-bit signed integer.

At some later stage you might also want to take a look at using

[Int64.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.tryparse.aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 64-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded or failed.

or [Int64.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.parse.aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 64-bit signed
>   integer equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

```
Thickness t = new Thickness(0);
if (value != null)
{ 
    t= new Thickness(System.Convert.ToInt64(((System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem)value).GetValue(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem.ContentProperty)));

}
return t;
```

Comment: u can change the above code for yourself  i had to convert combobox value to thickness class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.